Finding the shortest distance from a point to a line
I've been using the following as a really good guide for this:
Orthogonal projection of a point onto a line
but I want to make sure that I have set this up, and understood it correctly. I have the following piecewise function
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def piecewise_linear(x):
    if x < 40:
        return 90
    elif 40 <= x <= 70:
        return 90 - (x-40)
    elif x > 70:
        return 60

# Create a vectorized version of the piecewise function
piecewise_vectorized = np.vectorize(piecewise_linear)

# Generate x values
x_values = np.arange(0, 100, 1)

# Compute y values using the piecewise function
y_values = piecewise_vectorized(x_values)

# Plot the function
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.plot(x_values, y_values, label='Piecewise Linear Function')
plt.title('Piecewise Linear Function')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('f(x)')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()

plt.show()


If I add some points to this, then I can calculate the distance from those points to the line using orthogonal projections. The Orthogonal Projection Thm guarantees that if these projections are orthogonal, then the length of the orthogonal complement is the shortest distance to the original point from the line.
For any point p = (x,y) where x < 40, the distance to f(x) will just be f(x) - y. The same will be true for any point where x > 70. The interesting part is the line in the middle. To find this I rewrite this as:
$$
(1)\quad (y-90) + (x-40) = 0 \quad 40 \le x \le 90
$$
This gives us the point $p_0$ = (40,90). To find the direction we just note that our slope is -1, which implies d = (1,-1). Then, for any given point p, the projection onto the line will be
$$
\textrm{proj}_dp = \frac{d^T(p - p_0)}{d^Td}d
$$
and then the shortest distance to the line for any point p will be given by:
$$
||(p-(40,90))-\textrm{proj}_dp||
$$
Have I set this up correctly? I'm trying to improve my conceptual understanding of linear algebra and its applications.

Are you trying to find the shortest Euclidean distance between a generic point $(x,y)$ and this piecewise graph? If so, then "For any point p = (x,y) where x < 40, the distance to f(x) will just be f(x) - y" is incorrect.

When $x\le40$ you are not guaranteed that the $y=90$ is the closest segment. The closest one might be the sloped line

@Andrei Even more: the closest point to $(x,y)$ might even be on the $y=60$ segment, if $y$ is very low.

@2'59'2 At most, if $x\le 40$, the closest point on the lower line is $(70,60)$, which is also on the sloped line.

@Andrei Right. I wasn't countering what you wrote, just trying to make OP see how far away from the $y=90$ line that closest point can be.

So, we. shouldn't treat the domains separate when doing our projections? In which case, if we have a point p = (40,60), then yeah; I see how the closest point on the line would be on the segment where y = 60. In which case, we would that be considered the orthogonal projection? It would be sitting along that line (although not on it)

I think the orthogonal projection rule might not be the most reliable in this case. One reason is because of the possibility that the point on the graph from which the optimal orthogonal projection can be made doesn't exist due to the way the domain is restricted; the shortest distance from the point to the graph may not always exist on an orthogonal projection. Take for example:

The point exists on an orthogonal projection off the segment $y=90$. However, it's apparent that the projection isn't the shortest path to the point. Another problematic situation is when there are multiple orthogonal projections that meet the point that are similar in length, shown below:

Here, we can draw perpendicular lines off the segments $y=90$ and $y=90-(x-40)$ to meet the point, and both projections seem to be very close in length (but not equal). The fact that one projection is the shortest path while another isn't shows that they aren't necessarily the best way to calculate the optimal distance.
My approach would be to take each segment of the piecewise function, and write an equation that shows me the distance values between a point $(a,b)$ and any point on the segment. The first segment of $f(x)$ is the line $y=90$, which means any point on the segment can be expressed in the form $(x,90)$. Now, we can calculate the distance between a point $(a,b)$ and a point $(x,90)$ by using the Pythagorean theorem (remembering to restrict the domain to $x<40$):
$d_1=\sqrt{(a-x)^2+(b-90)^2}\;\;\;\{x<40\}$
We can do the same process for the second and third segments of $f(x)$:
$d_2=\sqrt{(a-x)^2+(b-(90-(x-40)))^2}\;\;\;\{40\le x\le70\}\\
d_3=\sqrt{(a-x)^2+(b-60)^2}\;\;\;\{x>70\}$
Now, if we graph all the distance equations, as well as $f(x)$ and a point $(a,b)$, we'll end up with something like this:

The black line is the graph of $f(x)$, and the purple line consists of the three distance functions that we wrote earlier. From the particular case pictured above, the lowest point of the purple distance line is $(70,41)$, which means that the distance between $f(x)$ at $x=70$ and the purple coordinate point $(a,b)$ is $41$ units. Since $(70,41)$ is the absolute minimum of the distance line, we can say that $(70,f(70))$ is the closest point of $f(x)$ to the point $(a,b)$. No matter where you move $(a,b)$, the distance line will always have an absolute minimum. The $x$-value of the minimum tells you the $x$-coordinate of the point on $f(x)$ that is closest to $(a,b)$, and the $y$-value of the minimum tells you the distance between the points. I've linked the graph below if you would like to refer to it:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4shbgg2cas
I'm not very experienced with programming, but hopefully there is a way to have your program automatically display the coordinates of the absolute minimum of the distance graph so you don't have to manually observe the graph each time you manipulate $(a,b)$. Let me know if this helps :)
